# text input with clear button which auto hide and show

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website where I have used a search box and inside that search input field I want to setup a reset button "X"

So, when search box input field is empty it will not show "X". But when the user types anything inside field then "X" will show up automatically.

Again, when the user clicks on "X" it will clear all typed data and still be focused inside input field?

Till now I have done this

ONLY JAVASCRIPT CODE I DO NOT USE jQuery!

```js
var searchSminput = document.getElementById("offcansearch").value.length;

if (searchSminput == 0) {
document.getElementById("resetb").style.display = "none";
} else {
document.getElementById("resetb").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
 #resetb {
  
  background-image: url(http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_286433.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 22px 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  width: 22px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 } 
  #offcansearch {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<form>
<input id="offcansearch" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
<button id="resetb" type="reset"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a change event to the input:

```
document.getElementById('offcansearch').addEventListener('change', function() { ... }
```

Also add to the reset button (on click hide the button):

```
resetb.addEventListener('click', function() {
  resetb.style.display = "none";
});
```

```js
var resetb =  document.getElementById("resetb");
var offcansearch = document.getElementById('offcansearch');

offcansearch.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var searchSminput = offcansearch.value.length;
  if (searchSminput == 0) {
    resetb.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    resetb.style.display = "block";
  }
});

resetb.addEventListener('click', function() {
  resetb.style.display = "none";
  offcansearch.focus();
});
```

```css
#resetb {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_286433.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 22px 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  width: 22px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#offcansearch {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="offcansearch" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  <button id="resetb" type="reset"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: excelent awnser. I'd just change the event to `keyup` or `keydown` instead of `change`. The `change` event only happens when the input lose focus.

Comment: i have to type 2 words then only it is working and not working every time I type ! something is wrong ! please check n help

Comment: yes now it started working ! only 1 thing left sir. when we click on clear button "X" to clear text. after then focus should be inside of search box not gone !

Comment: @DanielH thx yup it's working now actually I was trying to fix this from 2 hours but some how I was not able to fix this. so I was frustrated totally. anyways thanks again

Comment: @ArchiPatel Cool, accept the answer when you can, good luck coding!